# Why is it not connecting to the Socket.io server side from the client side?

Tags: sockets

I'm doing chat on nestJS, React, Socket.io. On the server side, I set the following parameters:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import {PrismaService} from "./prisma.service";
import * as socketio from 'socket.io';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  const prismaService = app.get(PrismaService);
  await prismaService.enableShutdownHooks(app)

  const server = await app.listen(3000);

  const io = new socketio.Server();
  io.attach(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: 'http://localhost:3001',
      methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
      allowedHeaders: 'Authorization',
      credentials: true
    },
  });
}
bootstrap();
```

But for some reason, when initializing the client part, it displays such an error

```
Websocket.js:40 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=ZfwUHiSBj2hwSS5UAAAE' failed:
```

How can I fix it?